# MySQL ERROR #1215 - cannot add foreign key constraint (relationship table cannot be created)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wamp, mysql-workbench

I search too much but I cannot find any solution or reason why I get this error.

First of all I have 3 table. I have one studenttable which has 1 primary key (nickname) and their passwords. I created that one without any problem.

Secondly, I have coursetable which has 2 primary keys, these are subject and course.

I want to create enrolledtable because I want to keep which stundent take which courses. So, I want to create relationship table with 3 primary keys. 1 of them is student's nickname and other 2 of them are course and subject. I get an error message like "#1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint".

I used mysql workbench 6.3 first. I try to solve that problem with WAMP but I cant I search too much but I cannot find any solution.

Student Table

[image]

Course Table

[image]

ERROR - Enrolled Table

[image]

In mysql workbench nickname and subject are not give an error, however, course cannot be primary key. I cannot select.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMwhD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMwhD.png)

SQL CODE

```
CREATE TABLE studenttable(
nickname VARCHAR(45),
pass VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (nickname)
);

CREATE TABLE coursetable(
subject VARCHAR(45),
course VARCHAR(45),
cname VARCHAR(45),
credit INT,
PRIMARY KEY (subject, course)
);

CREATE TABLE enrolledtable (
nickname VARCHAR(45),
subject VARCHAR(45),
course VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (nickname, subject, course),
FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES studenttable (nickname),
FOREIGN KEY (subject) REFERENCES coursetable (subject),
FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES coursetable (course));
```

Comment: course does not have to be primary key it just as to be a key.

Comment: No. I want primary key for course. Subject is like cs (computer science), math, ie (industrial engineering) but course is 306 (cs306  = database systems), 307 (cs307 = operating systems) which are meaningful when you combine them.

Comment: and also you can create table with 2 primary keys. It is Composite Primary Key in database systems

Comment: it would be better if you added your table definitions as text to the question or to sql fiddle - at least then we can pick them up and debug them for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql is very clear on the requirements for foreign key of which *MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan. In the referencing table, there must be an index where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order* is pertinent.
so this is ok

```
drop table if exists enrolledtable;
drop table if exists coursetable;
drop table if exists studenttable;

CREATE TABLE studenttable(
nickname VARCHAR(45),
pass VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (nickname)
);

CREATE TABLE coursetable(
subject VARCHAR(45),
course VARCHAR(45),
cname VARCHAR(45),
credit INT,
PRIMARY KEY (subject, course),
key k1 (course)                     #added
);

CREATE TABLE enrolledtable (
nickname VARCHAR(45),
subject VARCHAR(45),
course VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (nickname, subject, course),
FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES studenttable (nickname),
FOREIGN KEY (subject) REFERENCES coursetable (subject),
FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES coursetable (course)
);
```

and so it this (although it may not make sense in the context of your db)

```
drop table if exists enrolledtable;
drop table if exists coursetable;
drop table if exists studenttable;

CREATE TABLE studenttable(
nickname VARCHAR(45),
pass VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (nickname)
);

CREATE TABLE coursetable(
subject VARCHAR(45),
course VARCHAR(45),
cname VARCHAR(45),
credit INT,
PRIMARY KEY (subject, course),
key k1 (course,cname,credit)                        #added
);

CREATE TABLE enrolledtable (
nickname VARCHAR(45),
subject VARCHAR(45),
course VARCHAR(45),
PRIMARY KEY (nickname, subject, course),
FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES studenttable (nickname),
FOREIGN KEY (subject) REFERENCES coursetable (subject),
FOREIGN KEY (course) REFERENCES coursetable (course)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

"course" in enrolledtable is not the same data type as the field it's referencing.
Your foreign key is an INT(11), but it's referencing a VARCHAR(45).

Comment: which data types are different? I also write "course INT(11)" but it is not working

Comment: Can you help me to fix. How can I write enrolledtable or studenttable?

Comment: You wrote "stu**n**denttable" in your query instead of "studenttable".

Comment: Sorry for that I try this and I get same error

    FOREIGN KEY (nickname) REFERENCES studenttable (nickname),

Comment: Try running the following query and see what it returns: "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;"

Comment: I fix studenttable, try again and get same error. What did you mean by  "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;"

Comment: It's a query you have to execute, just like the query you use to create tables.

Comment: I changed my answer. Your foreign key is an INT(11), but it's referencing a VARCHAR(45).